# Batch File Logging - FOR /F need to log output message, date & time and %%I

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to log the output from `For /f` to a file.

This is what I have so far:

```
for %%x in ("<FILELOCATION>\*.csv") do (
For /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (%%x) do <COMMAND> & ECHO %%~I %date%, %time% >&1 >&2 >>C:\0-Migration\log.txt 
)
```

This produces a log file with %%I and the date and time, what i need to do is also add the output result of running the command.

So currently the log looks like this

```
USERNAME 13/05/2015, 11:48:16.68
```

And I need it to be like this

```
SamAccountName 13/05/2015, 11:48:16.68 No records had been updated.
```

No records had been updated is the result once the command runs.

Also if this is used

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (%%x) do <COMMAND> >>C:\0-Migration\log.txt
```

the log file has `"No records had been updated."` as the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in ("<FILELOCATION>\*.csv") do (
For /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (%%x) do ( 
       <COMMAND> 2>&1 1>>C:\0-Migration\log.txt 
       ECHO %%~I !date!, !time!  2>&1 1>>C:\0-Migration\log.txt 
)
```

the `<command>` output was not redirrected